# Adding elements into accordion

Tags: jquery

Adding elements to the

#### First

for a tab in the accordion breaks it. I'm looking to add some images into there that can be manipulated through css http://jsfiddle.net/4wSqn/5/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an image (http://jsfiddle.net/ZzqkG/) and it works perfectly, so it must have to do with your browser. Which one are you using? Try the latest version of Firefox/Opera/Safari/Ie and it will most probably work like you want it to.

Cheers.

Comment: Hi Robin, thank you for your reply but I meant in the header of each accordion tab, so where it says first.

Comment: Aww sorry my fault, but I don't think what you want is possible with jquery UI due to their css restrictions. You should try to google for an alternative tabbing interface or write one your own.
You could also try to alter the jquery Ui css but that's hardcore as it is really difficult to understand.